# How to revert an instance to use the class attribute instead of the shadowing instance attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, language-lawyer, instance-variables, class-attributes

If I have a class, and two instances of it:

```
class Foo:
    var = 1

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
```

Both of the instances' `var` attributes reflect the value I will set for `Foo`:

```
Foo.var = 2
print(a.var)  # 2
print(b.var)  # 2
```

But when I then set `var` for just `a`, `a.var` isn't anymore "in sync" with `Foo.var`:

```
a.var = 3
Foo.var = 4
print(a.var)  # 3
print(b.var)  # 4
```

Can I somehow "revert" this *without creating a new instance* so that `a.var` will once again reflect the value of `Foo.var`?

The obvious attempt doesn't (obviously) work, since integers are not references:

```
a.var = Foo.var
print(a.var)  # 4
Foo.var = 5
print(a.var)  # 5
```

Comment: ...`del a.var`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, that was embarrassingly simple, thanks!, I took that as an answer, in case someone else will wonder this in the future :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance attribute can just be deleted and then `a` will once again use the `var` defined in `Foo`:

```
del a.var
Foo.var = 6
print(a.var)  # 6
```